# Store info about current_user in constants to avoid unnecessary db hits - rails

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have many methods that get info about the current user, such as:

```
  current_user.is_admin?
  current_user.is_student?
  current_user.is_teacher?
```

These methods need to evaluate if the current_user (has_many :accounts) has an account with a corresponding role (student, admin, etc).

I could create something in the database to consolidate this, but that seems unnecessary.

Is there a rails way of defining true or false once at log in and then be able to reference later without querying?  In other words, def is_admin? would be defined as a constant with a true/false value at user_session create.  And, then I would never have to again query the users accounts to deterring if they were an admin.

Comment: "cache" and "caching" are the words you need to search against. Loads of options.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use session storage

```
def role
    session[:role] ||= 'student'
end

def is_admin?
    role == 'admin'    
end
```

But it's so tiny, keeping it in database is not going to hurt and the chances are you're retrieving the user from database for most of the requests anyway.

Comment: I find sessions to be a bit fragile...and not secure.  But, your answer got me in the docs.  I did not know that rails has just the answer for this.  You can use active_record_store for sessions and store the session data in the database.  Rails also give us "rake db:sessions:create" to create the table for those sessions.  Hot dog!

Comment: Cookies' data is signed, so nobody can tamper with it. They can read it but this doesn't seem to be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has an answer for this.

## Step 1

go into session_store.rb initializer and change the default from:

```
  Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: xxxx
```

to

```
 Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: xxx
```

Then, add a table to store session data in the db using:

```
 rake db:sessions:create
```

Comment: This has changed in rails 4.  Cookies are now signed...and encrypted if you set "secret_key_base".  Cooke_store is also faster, evidently.  So, in rails 4 the default cookie_store seems the way to go.